# 1px white border on side of table in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an issue where there is a small 1px border on the right hand side of the nemo image in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013, as shown below...

[image: Outlook email issue]

However, this doesn't happen in any other email browser... Here is the HTML code I am using...

```
<div id="top" align="center" style="background:#fff400; background-color:#fff400;">

<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5px; color:#636363; width: 100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="hide">

  <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="20" width="1"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;">



   <table align="center" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5px; color:#636363; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table">

  <tbody><tr>
   <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="20"></td>
    <td width="600" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:12px;">
      Click <a href="#" style="color: #00000;">here</a> if you can't read this email
      </td>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" width="20"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>




    </td>
  </tr>


    <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="20" width="1"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>


<table align="center" width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5px; color:#636363; " bgcolor="#FFF400" class="table">

  <tbody><tr>
    <td width="580" align="left" bgcolor="#fff400" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000001; font-size:9px;"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="15" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>


  <tr style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000;" align="left" valign="top">
    <td align="left" valign="top">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/172/115" width="172" height="115" alt="Alt Tag" style="display:block;" border="0" class="mob_img hide"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placekitten.com/406/115" width="406" height="115" alt="The 10 Minute Shake Up" style="display:block;" border="0" class="mob_img"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="20" width="1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
        <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.5px; color:#636363; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="table300">

  <tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><span id="nemotopmobile"><img id="nemotop" src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/nemoDesktop_08.jpg" width="640" height="15" alt="" class="mob_img " style="display:block;" border="0"></span></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:15px;"><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="20" height="1" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top">


    <table align="left" width="270" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mob_left table300">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#00b3f0; font-size:24px; padding-top:10px;"><img src="http://placekitten.com/270/88" width="270" height="88" alt="" class="mob_img " style="display:block;" border="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:20px; padding-top:10px;"><strong>Hello {Name},</strong></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:15px;"><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="16" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras pretium mi vel magna rhoncus, et pulvinar mauris varius. Nullam tincidunt, ipsum in eleifend tincidunt, tortor turpis viverra turpis, vehicula facilisis dui arcu quis sem. Aenean tincidunt diam orci, eget feugiat ante gravida eu. Fusce venenatis mollis nisi eget vulputate. Vestibulum ut turpis eget urna tincidunt volutpat sed at lorem. Donec non neque eget mauris gravida fringilla.</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:15px;"><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="16" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:15px;"><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="16" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody></table>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="table" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;">
      <tbody><tr>
          <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="nemoswitch"><img src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne/images/nemoDesktop_11.jpg" width="310" height="408" alt="Finding Nemo" id="nemo" class="mob_img" style="display:block;" border="0"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>



    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><span id="nemobottomswitch"><img id="nemoBottom" src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/nemoDesktop_16.jpg" width="640" height="15" alt="" class="mob_img " style="display:block;" border="0"></span></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[Here is a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU328/1/). Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a background color in your table cell.

To fix, simply add the following to your embedded styles:

```
table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

Or you can add it inline:

```
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;">... </td>
```

Checkout this [post](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3392/1px-borders-padding-on-table-cells-in-outlook-07/)

Comment: tried this, it was already in the head of the document... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your table(where you have a issue) you have used colspan="3". But your table only have two column. No idea why you have added colspan="3".

Change this

```
 <td colspan="3"><span id="nemotopmobile"><img id="nemotop" src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/nemoDesktop_08.jpg" width="640" height="15" alt="" class="mob_img " style="display:block;" border="0"></span></td>
```

To

```
 <td colspan="2"><span id="nemotopmobile"><img id="nemotop" src="http://design.datalateral.com\serco\73851\emails\emailOne\images/nemoDesktop_08.jpg" width="640" height="15" alt="" class="mob_img " style="display:block;" border="0"></span></td>
```

Do the same thing for the bottom row also.